# SonataAdmin : how to manage roles?

Tags: symfony, symfony-sonata

how to manage **roles** in sonataAdmin ?

i want to add new roles in the admin, and use it.

how to display dashboard tables depends on users roles ?

Exemple: want to display only some groups tables if users got a specific roles, don't want to show all content

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just define a good roles hierarchy and it must be good